# How to highlight polygons around my geolocation?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using the ArcGIS JavaScript API to create a map. I need to select/highlight polygons on my feature layers around my geolocation. I use in-build "LocateButton" function for geolocation.
I looked through all examples on Esri developer webpage and none of them are useful.

Do you have any idea how it can be done?

Comment: You might be able to create a point object using the location and pass that back as a query (or buffer) to select the features.  Are you representing the location on the map?

Answer (score 1):

1. use the [locate](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/locatebutton-amd.html#event-locate) event emitted by the widget as your opportunity to get a reference to the geolocated coordinates.

```
    geoLocate = new LocateButton({
      map: map
    }, "LocateButton");

    geoLocate.startup();
    geoLocate.on('locate', function(evt) {
      console.log(evt.graphic.geometry);
    });
```

2. pass this geometry in a spatial query to your feature service of interest.

you can find an example of an app which fires a spatial query [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_bypoly.html)